# How to change Symfony Sonata's flash message

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

The default flash message in Sonata admin bundle adds the key and value to the message:

Item "AppBundle\Entity\Users:00000000342d9b58000000004a2ab3f9" has been successfully created.

Could someone tell me how to get rid of the key and just have the value displayed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an answer to this question on sonata project github.
Try to add __toString($object) method to your Sonata Admin class:

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use App\Entity\Category;

class CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    public function toString($object)
    {
        return $object instanceof Category
            ? $object->getName()
            : 'Category'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For example override flash_create_success -> (Item "%name%" has been successfully created.), you need to create SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff file in your SonataAdminBundle's child and after that insert into file:

```
        <trans-unit id="flash_create_success">
            <source>flash_create_success</source>
            <target>WHAT DO YOU WANT TO SHOW.</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

Clear cache and test :)